# Regex to match string where '.' appears exactly x times

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am currently using `^(www)([0-9]{1,3})?(\.)` to match domains that being with www., www2. etc.

Ideally, I would like to be able to match only domains that have **at least two** periods in the given string, e.g. www2.xyz -> false | www2.domain.xyz -> true.

Is this possible, or do I need to process the match results separately after using the regex above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^www(?:[0-9]{1,3})?(?:\.[^.\s]+){2}
```

Here `(?:\.[^.]+){2}` part ensures that there are at least 2 dots in your address

Comment: This assumes the address starts with www though, which might not always be true.

Comment: Yes It is not matching all domain addresses. As per OP it needs to match `www`, `www2`, `www10` etc at the start.

Comment: I'd add `\s` to negated character class to restrict matches going far beyond.

Comment: Excellent. The `(\.[^.\s]+){2}` is exactly what I was looking for. @anubhava, is there a specific reason to switch these to non-capturing groups? I know at this point I am only returning true or false, but is that the only reason not to use them?

Comment: Non capturing groups save extra memory that is spent in storing capturing groups but for a small regex it doesn't matter much